# What is the best way to save and load variables?

Tags: lua, coronasdk

I have a bunch of variables like "Upgrades bought", "Amount of money" etc.
I want the most efficient way to save these variables and load them upon starting the game, as you never even exited the game (every single thing stays the same).
So, all the settings and variables stay the same, until you reset the game.

I am asking since I think this is a huge and really important part and I want to begin with the best technique.

What are your suggestions and how can I implement that in my game?

Comment: save those values to a file and load them whenever needed. check out json for a simple way to store lua tables. regarding your question please see [ask] or take the [tour]

Comment: @Piglet: You can use *Lua* to store Lua tables. Using JSON to store Lua tables is just... silly.

Comment: @NicolBolas and would you care to enlighten me why this is so silly?

Comment: @Piglet: The reason why JSON is useful in the JavaScript world is that JSON *is JavaScript*. It is a piece of executable JavaScript that will return a constructed object containing the data. Since it's JavaScript, and you're writing in JavaScript, you have the ability to "parse" that data format by simply executing it. You don't need to write a parser or file format. Lua can do the *exact same thing*. And it can be written *in Lua*, just like JSON is JavaScript. If you're already working in Lua, there's no reason to use JSON *unless* you're reading data written by someone else (or vice versa).

Comment: I always store external data in JSON. Just because encode and decode to Lua table is just a single line. And JSON is far much useful if you send it to a web server.

Answer (score 1):

You can store them as table fields and then serialize the table using one of the [many options for serializers](http://lua-users.org/wiki/TableSerialization). See also the [Serialization chapter](http://www.lua.org/pil/12.1.html) in Programming in Lua.

Comment: So, basically, I put all of my variables into a table and save the table. Upon starting my app, I load that table from some sort of file?

Comment: @FICHEKK yes. as simple as that

Answer (score 0):

There are two ways to do fairly easily:

Using a simple text file saved to your DocumentDirectory:

```
local filePath = system.pathForFile( "data.txt", system.DocumentsDirectory )
local file = io.open( filePath, "r" )
if file then
    -- read all contents of file into a string
    local contents = file:read( "*a" )

    print( "Contents of " .. filePath )
    print( contents )

    io.close( file )

    local t = display.newText( "Contents of ", 5, 80, nil, 16 );
    t:setFillColor( 1, 1, 136/255 );
    local t = display.newText( filePath, 5, 100, nil, 10 );
    t:setFillColor( 1, 1, 136/255 );

    local ylast = 130
    for line in io.lines(filePath) do  
        local t = display.newText( line, 15, ylast, nil, 14 );
        t:setFillColor( 1, 1, 1 );  
        ylast = ylast + 20
    end

else
    print( "Creating file..." )

    -- create file b/c it doesn't exist yet
    file = io.open( filePath, "w" )
    file:write( "Feed me data!\n" )
    local numbers = {1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9}
    file:write( numbers[1], numbers[2], numbers[3], "\n" )
    for _,v in ipairs( numbers ) do
        file:write( v, " " )
    end
    file:write( "\nNo more data\n" )
    io.close( file )

    local t = display.newText( "Created file at:", 5, 80, nil, 16 );
    t:setFillColor( 1, 1, 136/255 );
    local t = display.newText( filePath, 5, 100, nil, 10 );
    t:setFillColor( 1, 1, 136/255 );
    local t = display.newText( "Run app again to test file read.", 5, 130, nil, 12 );
    t:setFillColor( 1, 1, 136/255 );

    -- This removes the file just created
    -- os.remove( filePath )
end
```

2) Using a sqlite file saved to your DocumentDirectory:

```
--Include sqlite
require "sqlite3"
--Open data.db.  If the file doesn't exist it will be created
local path = system.pathForFile("data.db", system.DocumentsDirectory)
db = sqlite3.open( path )   

--Handle the applicationExit event to close the db
local function onSystemEvent( event )
        if( event.type == "applicationExit" ) then              
            db:close()
        end
end

--Setup the table if it doesn't exist
local tablesetup = [[CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS test (id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY, content, content2);]]
print(tablesetup)
db:exec( tablesetup )

--Add rows with a auto index in 'id'. You don't need to specify a set of values because we're populating all of them
local testvalue = {}
testvalue[1] = 'Hello'
testvalue[2] = 'World'
testvalue[3] = 'Lua'
local tablefill =[[INSERT INTO test VALUES (NULL, ']]..testvalue[1]..[[',']]..testvalue[2]..[['); ]]
local tablefill2 =[[INSERT INTO test VALUES (NULL, ']]..testvalue[2]..[[',']]..testvalue[1]..[['); ]]
local tablefill3 =[[INSERT INTO test VALUES (NULL, ']]..testvalue[1]..[[',']]..testvalue[3]..[['); ]]
db:exec( tablefill )
db:exec( tablefill2 )
db:exec( tablefill3 )

--print the sqlite version to the terminal
print( "version " .. sqlite3.version() )

--print all the table contents
for row in db:nrows("SELECT * FROM test") do
  local text = row.content.." "..row.content2
  local t = display.newText(text, 20, 120 + (20 * row.id), native.systemFont, 16)
  t:setFillColor(1,0,1)
end
```

You can also use a cloud based which is virtually the same thing with more mobility.

Answer (score 0):

Use any serializer or make your own:

```
function deepStructure (tabl, struct)
    local str = struct.." = {}" .. '\n'
    for i, v in pairs (tabl) do
        local index = type (i) == "string" and '.'..i or '['..i..']'
        if type (v) == "table" then
            str = str .. deepStructure (v, struct..index) .. '\n'
        elseif (type (v) == "string") then
            str = str .. struct .. index .. ' = ' .. '"'..tostring (v)..'"' .. '\n'
        else
            str = str .. struct .. index .. ' = ' .. tostring (v) .. '\n'
        end
    end
    return string.sub(str, 1, -2)
end
```

Example:

```
data = {1,2,3, t = {a="a", b="b", c=true, {7, true, "text"}}}
print (deepStructure (data, "data"))
```

Result:

```
data = {}
data[1] = 1
data[2] = 2
data[3] = 3
data.t = {}
data.t[1] = {}
data.t[1][1] = 7
data.t[1][2] = true
data.t[1][3] = "text"
data.t.b = "b"
data.t.a = "a"
data.t.c = true
```

As you see, they have the same structure until functions or dashes in name.